# Extreme lag issues in creative mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For some reason when I am in creative mode, I lag so badly, but when I switch to spectator mode, my game is completely okay.  But the thing is what is causing the lag in creative mode?  I checked the debug profiler and the tick percentage rules over everything and I pressed "1" on the keyboard and it says something unspecified is lagging the game.  Also, turning every setting to increase fps doesn't help and it is exactly the same as having my regular settings.  Any clues what this is?

[image]

Comment: Let us debug a bit! Is the game modded? does it happen in any other world? Does it happen in survival? How many mobs are around you? What did you do before the game started doing this (Was it since the creation of the world?)?

Comment: Yes I used fabric and the grow every minute challenge mod.  It lags in survival also, there are like only 10 mobs around me.  It wasn't lagging that much when the world was created

Comment: Mods... right... Well, there is an absurd chance that the problem are the mods. That is why it shows as unspecific. The grow every minute is very likely the problem. It is up to you to find out the problem, since I can't debugg it for you.

Comment: That looks like a very big hole. Are you using a bunch of tnt?

Comment: It was used by a nuke, but that world has been converted to 1.16.5.  The nuke doesn't exist and I didn't used any TNT since the lag happened.

Answer (score 1):

The lag disappearing when you switch to spectator mode could possibly suggest that your random tick speed is set to an extremely high number, causing lag. Random ticks usually occur around the player, but not around players in spectator mode.

Try to set the random tick speed to 3 (the default value).

```
/gamerule randomTickSpeed 3
```

Comment: My random tick speed is at 3, but the lag still happens